# Data view Web part in Page Layout

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, page-layout

I created a data view web part to display bread crumb(based on my site categories) on my sharepoint 2010 site.
After creation I exported the webpart and uploaded to Web part gallery.

When I try to add web part in webpart zone by editing any page, it works fine.

I need to add this webpart on every page of my site so I thought of adding it in the layout page.

So I added the webpart in the page layout using SPD. But it is not displaying.
My layout has has other web parts (some custom web parts and rating control) also and they are displaying properly.

It seems like that DVWP can not be added to page layout because when I edited the pages after adding the web part the zone was empty.

Could someone suggest something on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Add the DataView Web parts to page layouts but the catch is that you need to delete the WebPartZones. Try to add DataViewWebparts as it is and don't wrap it under WebPartZones.

Thanks